# Web application gives http method is not supported by this url error and also SQL error

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I'm creating a web application which, when we are going to it, gives an 'http method is not supported by this url; error and also an SQL error.

Please let me know that where the problem is.  Sometimes it is giving an SQL error and now it is giving 'http method post is not supported by this url' error.

Can you you please provide the way for running it successfully?

index.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"       

   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>My Web Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
     </head>
    <body>
    <table width="100%" height="15%">
    <tr>
    <td><h2>**My Web Project**</h2>
     <td width="200px"></td>
    <td>
    <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/webapp1/login">
     UserName: <input type="text" name="usern" class="textbox">
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass" class="textbox">
    <input type="submit" value="login" class="circle" >
    </form>.....
```

login.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String username1 = request.getParameter("usern");
            String password1 = request.getParameter("pass");
            System.out.println(username1);

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userlogin?useSSL=false", "root",
                    "root");
            System.out.println("hi");
            java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = con
                    .prepareStatement("select *from test where username=?");
            ps.setString(1, username1);


            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                String firstname = rs.getString("firstname");
                String bday = rs.getString("birth_day");
                String bmonth = rs.getString("birth_month");
                String byear = rs.getString("birth_year");
                String gender = rs.getString("gender");

                response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/webapp1/Userhome.jsp");

            } else {
                response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/webapp1/index.jsp?result=Failure");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("we got some error");
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.sendRedirect("SessionExpire.jsp");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not store passwords as plain-text. *Always* use a password-grade hashing system like [BCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) or [Scrypt](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/scrypt/SCryptPasswordEncoder.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `doPost` as

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
                      HttpServletResponse  response, String geek) 
        throws ServletException, IOException
```

The problem is the "geek" parameter that you have added.  That causes your method's signature to not matches the standard `doPost` method signature.  That means that you are *overloading* `doPost` rather than overriding it.

The consequence is that the servlet won't call your `doPost` at all.  Instead, it calls the method that you should have overridden ... whose behavior is to say "POST not supported".

Solution: get rid of the bogus `geek` parameter

Solution 2:  add an `@Override` annotation to the method.  That will cause the compiler to **tell you** if the method is not an override.

Comment: So have you checked that your doPost method is being called?

Comment: Suggestion: read the logfile that `e.printStackTrace()` will be writing to and look for a stacktrace.